# C++ Linker failure because of symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm writing some C++ code, mind you i'm new to the language. I have resolved all the errors when compiling with G++ but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting linking failure.

I've attached my code and the error:

Error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 algorithm.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Graph::Graph()", referenced from:
      _main in algorithm-14102f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My file(which is incomplete at the moment):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Graph {
    struct node {  // nodes that you read
       string name;
       int id;            // index of the node in the nodes vector
       vector<int> in;    // parent(s) that can lead to this node
       vector<int> out;   // children you can go to
        node(string key, int ind, vector<int> *in = new vector<int>(), vector<int> *out = new vector<int>()) : 
            name(key), id(ind) {}
    };
    vector<node> nodes;    // all the nodes in arbitrary sequential order
    map <string, int> dict; // map converting the names into ids
    public:
        Graph(); // class constructor
    void addNode(string key, int id){
        node *item = new node(key, id);
    }
    int getNodesLength(){
        return nodes.size();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Graph * graph = new Graph();

    std::string s;
    std::string word;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        for(char c : s) {
            if (c == ' '){ // right side words
                graph->addNode(word, graph->getNodesLength());



                word = "";
            } else if (c == ':') { // left side word
                graph->addNode(word, graph->getNodesLength());



                word = "";
            } else { // letter char
                word += c;  //  
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not implement `Graph::Graph()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you did not implement the constructor of the Graph class. Either dont declare it in the header (so the compiler will generate for you a default constructor), or if you do, implement it.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to C++, as I'm sure you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

`Graph * graph = new Graph();` `Graph` is already at the top level namespace.

You also forgot to provide the `constructor`

Comment: @bdeo where is Graph's constructor